# replacing existing url in url bar from angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have code to replace the url in the browser address bar. Before the url  is replaced, an alert is shown to indicate the change. Upon clicking the alert dialog, the url changes back to the original. How can I change the url in the address bar from an angularjs controller so that the change persists?

Here is my attempt:

```
$scope.goToDashboard = function () {
    window.history.replaceState("data", "Dashboard", "/dashboard");
    // on reaching here the url bar is /dashboard and on clicking it, it returns to the previous url
    alert("here...2");
    $scope.show = true;
}
```

How can I permanently rewrite the url with a new string?

Comment: `$location.url('/dashboard');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Above solution should work, but if you're thinking of angular things to be work smoothly, you might need to run digest digest cycle manually.

Rather I'd suggest you to do this by angular way, using `$location` API.

```
$location.url('/dashboard').replace();
```